# Variable set in ng-init is undefined in Laravel 5

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I have used following code:

```html
<div ng-app="" ng-init="quantity=1;cost=5">
<p>Total in dollar: {{ quantity * cost }}</p>
</div>
```

And it throws error: `Use of undefined constant quantity - assumed 'quantity'`
I'm using Laravel 5. How should be done in it using ng-init?

Comment: Why don't you init data in controller ?

Comment: I'm learning AngularJS now and I'm trying some examples...

Comment: It is more related to angular JS than laravel. `ng-app` attribute is where you declare your angular app. `ng-init` can't work outside an angular app. I guess you dont need to code angular js, so just add something to ng-app to name your application like `ng-app="app"`.

Comment: @MacKentoch `ng-app` is default directive in angular. @CI_lover will you please provide a plunker ?

Comment: @Vineet you are right. but this directive can be bypassed if you manually bootstrap your application (example your code in ES6). The main problem here is that app is not declared so angular js can't work.

Comment: I see this from this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_expressions  . I set ng-app="app" but still the same error. I think it's due to laravel variables syntax.

Comment: did you include `<script>` tag for angular js framework?

Comment: At the top of my test.blade.php file I extend app - @extends('app') and in it I have included it -  <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: check your browser resources (Chrome is the best for that) and be sure angular js is really loaded. As @Vineet well suggested before please provide us some kind plunker.

Comment: It's here, but it's not in laravel - http://plnkr.co/edit/gLUzE73mtHVKJ014ugfL?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

In your plunker, you included by mistake angular 2.

*Angular2 is totally different from angular js.*

Instantiate manually your angular app to prevent from bad experience :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-init="quantity=1;cost=5">

      <p>Total in dollar: {{ quantity * cost }}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      (function(){
        'use strict';
        //init angular JS app
        angular.module('app', [])
      })();

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried in a separate file and it's working. It's not working in Laravel 5 framework. It's giving `undefined variable`. variables in Laravel are written in this way in blade template: `{{$var}}` but in this case using angularJS I don't know how to write this variable.

Comment: I did it in Laravel in this way: `<div ng-app="app" ng-init="{{$quantity=1,$cost=5}}">
<p>Total in dollar: {{ $quantity * $cost }}</p>` Thank you all!
</div>